# Why does app crash when setting a property with a __block identifier

Tags: ios, crash, testflight

Im trying to set a UITextView's text property with this code but I get a crash saying I can't do it from the main thread:

```
__block NSString *stringForText;

self.uploadTask = [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:body completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // ...
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    int errorCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
    NSString *errorStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",errorCode];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *totalResponse = [errorStatus stringByAppendingString:responseString];

    stringForText = totalResponse;
    [self updateView:stringForText];

    // 4
    self.uploadView.hidden = NO;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}];


// 5
[_uploadTask resume];
}

-(void)updateView:(NSString*)texto{
    self.myTextView.text = texto;
}
```

Why does it crash saying I can't call it from the main thread in TestFlight?

Comment: I think you are well versed with SO. Please add actual error/ stack trace and expected output with problem other wise it will attract only down votes from many.

Comment: Thanks @PranavSingh I actually wasn't aware that that generated down votes. I actually thought it had something to do with the main thread as mentioned but wasn't sure. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I don't know what happened, the title of the question was actually cut off when I tried to post.  I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check again. You *must* update the UI from the main thread. It is likely your upload completion handler is operating off of the main thread. If you would like to call `updateView:` from any thread, then the you can dispatch the manipulation of the label to the main thread:

```
-(void)updateView:(NSString*)texto{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myTextView.text = texto;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're doing all of your work on the main thread.  Once the upload completes, dispatch into the main queue:

```
__block NSString *stringForText;

self.uploadTask = [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:body completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

        // ...
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        int errorCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
        NSString *errorStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",errorCode];

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *totalResponse = [errorStatus stringByAppendingString:responseString];

        stringForText = totalResponse;
        [self updateView:stringForText];

        // 4
        self.uploadView.hidden = NO;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    });
}];


// 5
[_uploadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because of exactly that—your block is being called on a background thread and UI elements need to be modified on the main thread.

Wrap `[self updateView:stringForText];` like `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self updateView:stringForText]; });`